# scraping youtube with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, dataframe, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I want to **scrape** the first two videos from the youtube search result, I have a list of words in CSV file I want to get the first two videos for each query, I tried to use selenium python but I get the error , so there is any way to do that.

CODE:

```
search_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#search').send_keys('')
```

ERROR:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: I would rather call https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=<SEARCH-TERM> instead of using search bar.

Comment: Best way to scrape could be to use its api.

Please take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more than one element when using your selector `#search`.

`.find_element_by_*` refers to the first element, sadly the input element you are referring to is not the first. The first element with your selector is a hidden element, that's what causes you to get the **`.....element not interactable`** error.

A unique locator for that is `input#search`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#search').send_keys('test')
```